# Weird behaviour on neovim inside a tmux when writting yaml files

Tags: neovim

I have a weird behavior in neovim when editing a YAML file, but it only happens when I run it inside tmux.

Given the file:

```
foo:               
  foo: value      
bar: value
```

if I use tmux+nvim to edit the `bar` value to anything like `value1`, when I write the file it has been modified indenting `bar`, like:

```
foo:
  foo: value
  bar: value1
```

As you can guess, that usually invalidates my yaml file, what avoids me moving to neovim.

The problem is that when I edit the same file with tmux+vim.tiny it works fine, as well as with neovim outside of tmux. I'm not sure about where to search or to ask... So finally I've decided to ask here to see if any of you have the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce with `nvim -u NORC test.yaml` inside tmux? What is your nvim version? I have tried nvim 0.6.1, can not reproduce. Maybe something wrong with your config instead of neovim. Try to bisect the issue. Your question is too vague for other to help you effectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for comming in, @jdhao.

I've tested with `nvim -u NORC` and same result.
I'm using nvim 0.4.4. I will try with 0.6.1.

Sorry very much for being so vague, but I have no clues about which the problem is. So any help is welcome.

Comment: Tested with version 0.6.0 and it is solved.
Thank you very much, @jdhao!